# Action Extension on iOS . How to share data like it work on Share Extension

Tags: ios, mobile

After successfully setup Share Extension , I am trying to share data throw action extension but don't know how to do that.

Do I need to delete extension files ? Is this possible to have functionality like Share extension ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about sharing data from the host app so that your extension will obtain it, or sharing data between your extension once it has it and your app?

For the former, it's been many years since I set up my action extension but I remember there being a lot of things to try and trial and error with getting  the info.plist correct. Here's how my action extension is configured to obtain vcard content i.e. contact content from the call history or from the contacts app etc.

[image]

Here's the contents of that activation rule in full:

```
SUBQUERY (extensionItems, $extensionItem,SUBQUERY ( $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.vcard").@count >= 1).@count > 0
```

How you configure this will depend upon what data you want to get.

Once your extension has obtained some data, to provide that data to your app you need to enable shared groups in both the app and the extension and then write the data to a file, or defaults, or you could launch the app from the extension and pass the data as a url scheme for example.

Comment: Thank you so much. The thing is , that I am a Flutter developer , and iOS is my weak side) . Can you also please say , what do I need to change for receive shared data to my app ?